# How to match a sub matrix which belongs in a big matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Suppose I have a `128 x 128` matrix, *(say A)*. I also have a `64 x 64` matrix, *(say B)*. The *B* matrix is in the *A* matrix. I **want to print "match found"** when the *B* matrix is found in the *A* matrix.

***thsd_submatrix*** is the matrix *B* & ***updated_mainImage*** is matrix *A*. I am creating a new_matrix (`64 x 64`) from `128 x 128` (*A*) matrix and want to match with "*thsd_submatrix*".

```
new_matrix = zeros(64,64);
for i=1:128
    for j=1:128
           new_matrix(1:64,1:64)=updated_mainImage(i:i+63,j:j+63);
        if(new_matrix==thsd_submatrix)
```

Comment: this might help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153596-how-to-find-a-subset-matrix-in-the-main-matrix-and-build-a-new-matrix

Comment: @AlexS1 i'm not getting the actual thing.

Comment: The approach you have in your code should work (though it may be slow). Just consider using `isequal(new_matrix,thsd_submatrix)` instead of the `==`. Alternatively add `all` qualifiers (`if` may do that automatically, I'm not sure, but it's not a good style).